# Finding identities for $\cos(a+\frac{\pi}{4} \mod \frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, modular-arithmetic

The question is rather self-explanatory, but I can't find good answers online.

The reason for wanting identities for this is that $b$ and $c$ are constants, and this formula is being used on a device with extensive but slow computing ability, and so any constants that can be calculated beforehand should be.

Again, the formula I want to find identities for, used to calculated $\omega$ is

$\omega = $$\cos(a+\frac{\pi}{4} \mod \frac{\pi}{2})$

Comment: Are $a, b, c$ integers? Does the device have a $\cos$ instruction, or do you run a series?

Comment: The device has a $\cos$ instruction, but it's slow. $a$ is between $0$ and $2\pi$. $b$ and $c$ are changed above.

Comment: Well, $\cos(x \mod \frac{\pi}{2})$ is one of $\cos(x), \sin(x), -\cos(x), -\sin(x)$. I'm not sure what improvement you're looking for. If you look at the graph, it should be clear that the $\cos$ will have to be computed. Is it the $\mod {}$ that you hope to save?

Comment: I'm trying to precompute as much as possible

Comment: [A graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%28x+%2B+pi%2F4+mod+pi%2F2%29). Note that it's curvy, so you *have* to compute $\cos$. Note that it's not continuous, so you *have* to compute $\mod {}$. We can talk about approximations (how much precision do you need?), or about optimizing your code (can you post it? do you know the duration of each instruction?), but not about algebraic manipulations.

Comment: I was planning on using a Taylor approximation to six terms, which isn't too bad, but limits the 'x' of the term to approximately 10, because of the exponentiation, and use of 32-bit values